# GWT and Generics

Tags: java, gwt, generics

We are having a SerializationException error when sending a list of objects using RPC and Java Generics.

I'm creating this widget to show the error:

```
public class Test<T> {

    ListDataProvider<T> ldp = new ListDataProvider<T>();

    public void setItems(List<T> list){
        for(T t :list){
            ldp.getList().add(t);
        }
    }

    public List<T> getItems(){
        return ldp.getList();

    }

}
```

This is the code for creating the Test widget and passing a list of POJOs (where ExporterFormKey is the POJO object)

```
List<ExporterFormKey> list = new ArrayList<ExporterFormKey>();
ExporterFormKey key = new ExporterFormKey();
key.setKey("key1");
list.add(key);

Test<ExporterFormKey> test = new Test<ExporterFormKey>();
test.setItems(list);
```

At the end the next code throws a SerializationException:

```
service.sendList(test.getList(), new AsyncCallback...);
```

While the next one does fine:

```
service.sendList(list, new AsyncCallback...);
```

-----Edit----

I found that doing the next code also works

```
List<ExporterFormKey> newList = new ArrayList<ExporterFormKey>();
newList.add(test.getItems().get(0));
service.sendList(newList , new AsyncCallback...);
```

Or this also works

```
List<ExporterFormKey> newList = new ArrayList<ExporterFormKey>(test.getItems());
```

I also found this change on Test works!

```
public List<T> getItems(){
    return new ArrayList<T>(ldp.getList());
}
```

Comment: You might have to cast test.getList() to type List<ExporterFormKey> or Declare Test with <T extends ExporterFormKey>.

Comment: Probably your ListDataProvider<T>() is not returning an ArrayList but another implementation of List (for instance a Collections.unmodifiableList() returned list or an AbstractList derived type. Could you please post the full SerializationException and the server log? It should say why serialization is failing and which is the offending class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.rubiconred.com/2011/04/gwt-serializationexception-on-rpc-call.html

As izaera suggested the ListDataProvider uses a non-serializable list implementation (ListWrapper) which cannot be sent directly across the wire.

Wrapping the response from ListDataProvider's getList() method into a new ArrayList as you have suggested in your post is the simplest way to workaround the issue.

Comment: In case someone is visiting here for an answer, the link above is now dead and returns a 404. The page also doesn't seem to be cached.